# Store only date and time (hours and minute) in .NET EF core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, datetime

Is it possible to remove second and millisecond from datetime format?

Usually, the format will be

> 2023-03-07T02:32:03.998Z

I found some answers that with the below format, the format data will be "yyyy-mm-dd"

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
```

so what should I do to get the format like this "HH-mm yyyy-MM-dd" when sending input from controller?

Comment: You really don't "send input from controller" (not even sure what it means)... and please stick to [ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/) in  API responses.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry for not clearing it, I mean when I enter the value for the model, the model contains 1 datetime value, it usually has day, month, year, hour, minute, second, and millisecond, how can I get rid of it? Like when I test API with swaggerUI, it wont display them or force me enter second and millisecond

Comment: Do you wanna change the default data format to “HH-mm yyyy-MM-dd” in swagger?

Comment: @XinranShen yes, as long as second and millisecond are not in the default format then I'm fine

Comment: You can set default data format to `yyyy-MM-dd` without hour and minute, I am not sure if you can accept this.

Answer (score 0):

You can format `DateTime` from the database with `.ToString("format")`

```
var formatedDateTime = ArrivalTime.ToString("HH-mm yyyy-MM-dd"); //returm string in given format
```

valid `C#` formats https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use 'DateTime' format string to remove the seconds and milliseconds.

Here, In the below code "ToString" is used to formate the DateTime object with the required formate ("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:00Z")

example:

```
string originalDateTimeString = "2023-03-07T02:32:03.998Z";
DateTime originalDateTime = DateTime.Parse(originalDateTimeString);

string updatedDateTimeString = originalDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MMddTHH:mm:00Z");

Console.WriteLine("Original datetime: " + originalDateTimeString);
Console.WriteLine("Updated datetime: " + updatedDateTimeString);
```

output:

```
Original datetime: 2023-03-07T02:32:03.998Z
Updated datetime: 2023-03-07T02:32:00Z
```

The seconds and milliseconds is removed in the updated datetime string.

(or)

If you need to modify a DateTime value while minimizing memory usage and garbage collection overhead, you could consider doing this.

```
DateTime originalDateTime = DateTime.Now; 
DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(originalDateTime.Year,originalDateTime.Month, originalDateTime.Day,originalDateTime.Hour, originalDateTime.Minute, 0);
```

Comment: Although you CAN do this. It is less efficient and produces more GC pressure than if you constructed a new DateTime from the properties.

Comment: Hi @Aron ,I don't think so, because when new object is created a memory needs to be allocated, the memory needs to be tracked and eventually cleaned up by the garbage collector. This can create additional memory pressure and overhead that can affect performance.

So, In this case modifying the existing object does not involve creating new object or allocating new memory this can be efficient and generate less garbage collection.

Comment: strings are objects too. In fact DateTime is NOT an `object`, it is a `struct`. Therefore `DateTime` does not affect the GC (unless you box it).

Comment: Yes but Ultimately, whether it is more efficient to modify an existing DateTime object or create a new one will depend on the specific use case and the trade-offs between memory usage, processing time, and other factors.
 If you need to modify a DateTime value while minimizing memory usage and garbage collection overhead, you could consider doing this,

`DateTime originalDateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(originalDateTime.Year,originalDateTime.Month, originalDateTime.Day,originalDateTime.Hour, originalDateTime.Minute, 0);`

Comment: "whether it is more efficient to modify an existing DateTime" `DateTime` is immutable. You CAN'T modify it. Not to mention, IT ISN'T AN OBJECT. It is a struct.

Comment: yes, Sorry for the confusion. DateTime is a struct in C# and is immutable,Therefore, modifying an existing DateTime is not possible.To remove the seconds and milliseconds from a DateTime value, we would need to create a new DateTime object with the desired value, as shown in the previous example.